# jQuery imageScroll not functioning properly with Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I got the following error message on my Chrome browser when adding [jQuery Plugin - Parallax ImageScroll](https://github.com/pederan/Parallax-ImageScroll) in page--node--xx.tpl.php. The error is the "jquery.imageScroll.js" file not functioning properly. I have tried JavaScript closures solutions from "[Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213)" with no luck. I don't know javascript and how to make it run properly.

*Error Message on Google Chrome web browser:*

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
_bindEvents
init
(anonymous function)
b.extend.each
b.fn.b.each
$.fn.imageScroll
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
```

*The Script I use to call js in page--node--xx.tpl.php*

```
<?php drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/js/jquery.imageScroll.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer')); ?>
```

*I have tired 3 JavaScript closure solutions on jquery.imageScroll.js with no luck*

1

```
(function () {
//all jquery.imageScroll.js script
$('.img-holder').imageScroll({
});
}());
```

2

```
(function ($) {
//all jquery.imageScroll.js script
$('.img-holder').imageScroll({
});
}(jQuery));
```

3

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//all jquery.imageScroll.js script
$('.img-holder').imageScroll({
});
});
```

---

***Update info on Dec. 10, 2014 at 12:58pm.*

I solve the error message by updating the jQuery verison using "[jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update)" module. However, the background image does not display at all.**

***Update info on Dec 11th, 2014 at 3:34pm***
For some reason, I have this new error on Google Chrome and images are still not showing up. They are...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
b.extend.ready
u
```